# VM Vulnerability assessment reports in csv file and send it to Artifact

Tags: qualys

I was looking for tools that I can use to scan my Linux VM Golden Image. I couldn't find a tool (all i got is for scanning container images) and ended up with Qualys. Now I am trying to do Vulnerability scan on the VM and send the reports in CSV format to an artifact using automation script. Can anyone suggest if that's possible with (Deploy the integrated vulnerability scanner powered by Qualys (included with Microsoft Defender for servers) or is there is any better tool.

I need a tool which can scan VM Golden Image or if we can Use Qualys against a VM and generate a csv report and store in Artifact